# I still don't understand public static void main(string [ ] args)

Tags: java

After almost 1 year working with Java,I still can not explain properly to others or myself why we need this, and how it works.

Obviously, I know what each of keywords does independantly, but I am not sure about the whole thing.

Can someone please describe it in very simple language?

Comment: It's the entry point to the program.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html#MAIN

Comment: Google [`what is java main`](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+java+main)

Comment: For one thing, `args` is not of type `string[]`, it's of type `String[]`.

Answer (score 3):

Public : is an Access Modifier, which defines who can access this Method. Public means that this Method will be accessible by any Class(If other Classes are able to access this Class.).

Static : is a keyword which identifies the class related thing. This means the given Method or variable is not instance related but Class related. It can be accessed without creating the instance of a Class.

Void : is used to define the Return Type of the Method. It defines what the method can return. Void means the Method will not return any value.

main: is the name of the Method. This Method name is searched by JVM as a starting point for an application with a particular signature only.

String args[] : is the parameter to the main Method.

Comment: Well written and an upvote to get you started on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct, but I'll try to state it in English.
When you create a program, java needs to know where to start the program, so they use this as an entry point. Since it's static method, there doesn't need to be an instantiation of the class. It can simply call that method and know that that's where the program starts.

Comment: For other programs using main - YES they do. In C there is main(), too. In windows C++ programs, there's WinMain()

Answer (score 1):

I knew these already thank you for you response and downvotes.

> public

It means that you can call this method from outside of the class you are currently in. This is necessary because this method is being called by the Java runtime system which is not located in you current class.

> static

When the JVM makes call to the main method there is no object existing for the class being called therefore it has to have static method to allow invocation from class.

> void

Java is platform independent language and if it will return some value then the value may mean different things to different platforms. Also there are other ways to exit the program on a multithreaded system. Detailed explaination.

> main

It's just the name of method. This name is fixed and as it's called by the JVM as entry point for an application.

> String args[]

These are the arguments of type String that your Java application accepts when you run it.

But why there is no simplar method to call main like in other languages, and why we need to get argument and store as String while we sometimes only call methods in the main.

Comment: I think you should edit your question and add this rather than posting an answer with a question.

Answer (score 1):

When you start a Java program the JVM needs to know where it should start the execution of the whole thing. This is not obvious because there are thousands of Java classes available on the classpath.
That's why you must give the name of one particular Java class in your command line. For example

```
java com.stackoverflow.example.Main bla blah
```

The JVM then just loads this class, looks for its `static void main(String[] args)` method, and calls it with the remaining parameters taken from the command line

```
main(new String[]{"bla", "blah"});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `main()` method is defined by the [`java`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BGBCIEFC) launcher:

> The `java` command starts a Java application. It does this by starting the Java Runtime Environment (JRE), loading the specified class, and calling that class's `main()` method. The method must be declared *public* and *static*, it must not return any value, and it must accept a `String` array as a parameter. The method declaration has the following form:
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args)
> ```

That explain why you need it: *It's required to start running a Java program.*
And how it works: *It's called by the launcher at startup.*